# Removing Small Regions from a Binary Image

Tags: java, image-processing

I need to remove all small contiguous regions that are smaller than a specified size in a binary image, equivalent to matlab's `bwareaopen` function. I have tried installing some libraries to do it but I didn't find a suitable solution.

Comment: I have tried to use libraries in ImageJ but this does not work.

Comment: you may call the matlab libraries, and if no success, you need to call it via a proxy (native code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageJ's [ParticleAnalyzer](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/plugin/filter/ParticleAnalyzer.html) can segment contigious regions (= particles) according to their size.

In order to get the necessary code, just run *Plugins > Macros > Record...* in the ImageJ GUI and switch the *Record:* mode to *Java*. Then run [*Analyze > Analyze Particles...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#toc-Subsection-30.2) and the recorder will show you the Java code necessary to reproduce the particle analysis.

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;

[...]

ImagePlus imp = // you have to know how to get your image
IJ.run(imp, "Analyze Particles...", "size=500-Infinity circularity=0.00-1.00 show=Masks in_situ");
```

This will replace the image in `imp` by the result image, equivalent to removing those particles outside the range specified by `size=500-Infinity`.

On a lower level, you can also use the `ParticleAnalyzer` class directly as follows:

```
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.measure.ResultsTable;
import ij.plugin.filter.ParticleAnalyzer;

[...]

ImagePlus imp = // you have to know how to get your image
ResultsTable rt = new ResultsTable();
Double min_size = 50.0;
Double max_size = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
ParticleAnalyzer pa = new ParticleAnalyzer(ParticleAnalyzer.SHOW_MASKS + ParticleAnalyzer.IN_SITU_SHOW, 0, rt, min_size, max_size);
pa.analyze(imp);
```

You might need to set a threshold on your binary image before doing this.

Comment: I have tried the code. It executed correctly but it was suitable to fill the small holes within large regions. I still have the small regions in the image.

Comment: This is due to ImageJ "confusing" foreground and background, a common issue caused by ImageJ's unintuitive way of [binarizing images with inverted look-up tables (LUTs)](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:technical:how_do_i_set_up_imagej_to_deal_with_white_particles_on_a_black_background_by_default). Try setting the binary options to use a black background by running `IJ.run("Options...", "iterations=1 count=1 black edm=Overwrite");` and see if this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the small and large regions you want to separate contain pixel intensities of 255, and the background has intensities of 0? If not, either invert your image or set a suitable threshold (`IJ.setThreshold(imp, 0, 128);`) and then convert it to binary (`IJ.run(imp, "Convert to Mask", "");`).

Comment: Actually it worked out using "options..." since I was using "Analayze..." instead. You saved me. Thank you so much!

Comment: How can I label the segmented regions to get some features like area, perimeter, diameter,etc?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [_Analyze Particles..._](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:Analyze-Particles...). Use the _Add to manager_ option to add every segmented region to the [ROI Manager](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:ROI-Manager...). The required Java code you can get via _Plugins > Macros > Record..._ and then choosing the Java record mode in the Recorder window. For advanced use, take a look at the [ROI Manager API](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/plugin/frame/RoiManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should try and integrate a processing system like [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) into your java code. I've done it before and it is fairly straight forward. It has a lot of plugins that others have created that you can then integrate into your java code.

For an example on how to integate ImageJ into you application have a look at [this link](http://albert.rierol.net/imagej_programming_tutorials.html#ImageJ). They give a clear example on how to do it.

Then its just a case of finding the correct steps to achieve what you want. You can first practice with the GUI and then code the steps.

Comment: Actually I have searched in ImageJ libraries but I did not find the specific function.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the MATLAB function directly from your java program: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html

Comment: Does this require to install matlab on my machine, i.e. Can I call some matlab functions from java code without installing matlab as full package? I am working on a project that requires using java only without installing matlab on clients machines.

Answer (score 0):

Search for morphological operations. In this case you are interested in `Open` operation. Which is mix of `Erosion` and `Dilation`.

For start I can recommend you [this guide](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm). Implementing those filters is quite easy. If you are concerned about performance, you should look into filter separability.

Another option would to use OpenCV, which has Java API. But I have only used C++ API, so you should consult documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest using MATLAB Builder JA. It wraps MATLAB functions to be used outside of MATLAB in a Java program; and you don't need MATLAB afterwards to run the Java program.

See this link: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/java-math.html

You need to make a MATLAB function: if only BWAREAOPEN, then wrap it in your own function, example:

'`function out = mybwareaopen(in)

out = bwareaopen(in)`

Then make a JAR file using MATLAB Builder JA, and call the "mybwareaopen" method in java.

Comment: I have wrapped bwareopen function but still having a problem while calling it in Java. It deals with an input parameter of type Object[] and it also returns Object[] not BufferedImage.